# Any way to share global variables between Struct & Class? @Environment doesn't work

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-environment

**Scenario:**

I have a tabbed-based application with **parallel network routines** of similar function.

[image]

Each has has its own network error handler which sends out a @Published alert flag to notify the calling host's alert operator to display the respective alert.

In this case, I have a 'No Internet' alert.

**Problem:**

Having only one (1) network error routine is okay... but having multiple-network routines creates multiple network errors which either:

1. Requires multiple .alert operators (one per tabbed network routine) or
2. Use a SINGLE .alert operator for all.

Option #1 is bad because all the .alerts would conflict with one-another on the SAME host.

That leaves option #2.

That would require me to have a GLOBAL alert flag that is shared amongst the parallel alert generators.

These alerts originate in parallel '**observable classes**', each containing  their network-handling logic (publisher) from which the host can harvest their respective alert messages via **@Observed** vars.

However, each parallel class CANNOT access the **@environment** to share a global property which would be shared within ONE single .alert() property on the host struct.

That is my problem.

**Note:** this is merely a *learning application* to model *different* network scenarios; and how to process their respective data *subjectively*.
...I could simplify this by merely checking the network ONCE vs each tabbed routine.

**Question:** How can I have various classes share a **global var** (bool flag & String message) generated by a class vs struct?

Would I need a class singleton and how would that be incorporated within the receiving stuct?

I have two worlds: class & strut that can need to share global data.

Comment: I would use instance of class adopting `ObservableObject` hosting somewhere in `AppDelegate` or `SceneDelegate`, so it could be referenced from other classes and injected via `@EnvironmentObject` in SwiftUI Views.

Comment: I had the same idea but I can't access an @EnvironmentObject from a struct.  That's my original problem.